# Cant find the 'object_detection' module from object_detection.protos

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I am using tensorflow object-detection api to detect objects from a video file in jupyter notebook.

currently my file is inside 'models/research/object detection' folder

the link of the code that i have taken from : https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/camera.html

```py
import numpy as np
import os
import six.moves.urllib as urllib
import sys
import tarfile
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile
import cv2

from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from utils import label_map_util # getting error right here
from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util
```

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-c2d31cb1df1e> in <module>
     12 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
     13 from PIL import Image
---> 14 from utils import label_map_util
     15 from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util
     16 import sys

E:\traffic-detector\models\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py in <module>
     24 import tensorflow as tf
     25 from google.protobuf import text_format
---> 26 from object_detection.protos import string_int_label_map_pb2
     27 
     28 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection'
```

I dont get it why does is say that

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set `PYTHONPATH` correctly. You should run the following command in folder `model/research/`.

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the full path to the directory which contains the module.
Probably `research` folder contains the `object_detection` module so the path being something like

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\\Tf_models\\models\\research\\")
```